# Garageband recognising both key up and key down on MIDI controller

Tags: garageband, midi

I recently upgraded from Venture to Sonoma and now my MIDI keyboard is registering both on key down and key up in Garageband (10.4.9).

A few other observations that seem odd:

- Garageband now says 3 inputs are connected when I connect the keyboard. However, in the audio tab, it only shows one controller. When I disconnect it says 1 is connected (but the settings say nothing is connected)
- the pedal no longer works
- things are working as expected in another DAW (Logic Pro)
- in the Audio Midi Setup screen for the OS, only key ups are registering (not sure what was happening on Ventura)

I have tried resetting the drivers but no luck.

Anyone have any troubleshooting tips/ideas what may be going on?

Comment: Have you checked to see if there's a driver update?

Comment: There are two places I have checked. Garageband allows you to refresh the driver (I have done that). The manufacturer unfortunately does not have an updated driver. Did you mean either of those?

Comment: Yes. You might have to contact the manufacturer & see what they have to say. I know Cubase users were warned by Steinberg not to update to Sonoma initially. I think they have that fixed though now.